# Eclipse plugin for abbreviations

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am looking for Eclipse plugin that would make smart completion even smarter. I mean for example:

throw new  -> IDE propose IllegalArgumentException.

I know that there is something like this in Netbeans and IntelliJ.

Comment: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/autocomplete  This was the only legit one I could find, I hope it helps you!

Comment: I would but apparently I have not enough points because the voting picture doesn't show up at your post.